# Vaadin setting background-images removes buttons' backgrounds

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I'm setting a background image for my page (based on a VerticalLayout) as described here:
https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17221780/setting-style-background-image-on-layout

This works well, the image is set. Unfortunately, the background of my buttons and text fields disappear, only their text is shown.

Can anybody explain why this happens and how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Are the buttons styled with tertiary or similar things? Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, the buttons use the lumo layout and are styled with "secondary". Using primary will use a non-transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is not a bug but a desired behavior. I did not see the light grey shadow meaning the buttons have a transparent color. Changing the background using css helped me to remove the transparency.